# PHP: spl_autoload_register + RecursiveDirectoryIterator

Tags: php, autoload, spl-autoload-register

I want to loop all the sub dirs in the main dirs, where I keeps all my classes, for instance,

```
core/
   model/
       page/
          class_1.php
          class_2.php
       menu/
          class_3.php
       and so on...
```

So this is my autoload function that I place it in the init.php,

```
function autoload_multiple_directory($class_name){

    // List all the class directories in the array.
    $array_directories = array(
        'core/controller/', 
        'core/model/',
        'core/helper/'
    );

    // When you use namespace in a class, you get something like this when you auto load that class \foo\tidy.
    // So use explode to split the string and then get the last item in the exloded array.
    $parts = explode('\\', $class_name);
    //print_r($parts);

    // Set the class file name.
    $file_name = strtolower(end($parts)).'.php';
    // $file_name = 'class_'.strtolower($class_name).'.php';

    // Loop the array.
    foreach($array_directories as $path_directory){


        $recursive_directory = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path_directory);
        foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($recursive_directory) as $filename => $file) {

            if(file_exists(WEBSITE_DOCROOT.$file->getPath().'/'.$file_name)){

                include WEBSITE_DOCROOT.$file->getPath().'/'.$file_name;
            } 

        }


        /* no problem with this, but I cannot loop the sub dirs...
        if(file_exists(WEBSITE_DOCROOT.$path_directory.$file_name)){

            include WEBSITE_DOCROOT.$path_directory.$file_name;
        }
         * 
         */
    }
}


spl_autoload_register('autoload_multiple_directory');
```

But then I get this error message,

Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Common in C:\wamp\www\xxx\core\helper\Common.php on line 6

There is only one `Common` class in my project. Why does it say **more than once** or **redeclare**?

But if you look at the `if(file_exists(WEBSITE_DOCROOT.$path_directory.$file_name))` that I comment out - it has no problem to load the classes. The problem of this initial loop is that it does not loop the sub dirs in a main dir, for instance, `core/model/`

Any ideas why and what should I do to loop the sub dirs of a main dir?

**EDIT:**

The problem comes from `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` - it loops the directories and lists all files. But what I want is only the sub directories.

Comment: It is because the `Common` class is declared more than once. Find the files where it is declared and choose one of them. And learn to make sense of error messages.

Comment: it is only one. if you look at the `if(file_exists(WEBSITE_DOCROOT.$path_directory.$file_name))` that I comment out - it has no problem to load the classes.

Comment: The error message says that it is being declared *more than once*. Saying otherwise does not change that.

Comment: there is only one `Common` class in my project. Why does it say `more than once.`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any chance that there are more than one copy of `Common.php` file exists in those folders?
Because your code does not `break` after including a class file the `autoloader` will continue seeking other files with the same name in the folder tree, and would lead to `Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class XXX` error. Adding `break` could fix the problem.

```
// Loop the array.
$isClassFound = false;
foreach($array_directories as $path_directory){
    $recursive_directory = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path_directory);
    foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($recursive_directory) as $filename => $file) {
        if(file_exists(WEBSITE_DOCROOT.$file->getPath().'/'.$file_name)){
            include WEBSITE_DOCROOT.$file->getPath().'/'.$file_name;
            $isClassFound = true;
        }
        if ($isClassFound) break;
    }
    if ($isClassFound) break;
}
```

However, the nature of your `autoloader` seems like it should not allow any duplicated class file names. Maybe you can write a name duplication checker to guarantee uniqueness.

### EDIT:

I removed the `class_exists()` part from my answer because using it doesn't make much sense. Anyway, since you saw that version of my answer, and you asked me where to put `class_exists()` via the comment, I'll revive the code sample. you can add the following code at the beginning of the `autoloader`.

```
if (class_exists($class_name,false)) // give false to avoid automatic loading
    return;
```

Comment: sorry, where should I put `class_exists` in my existing code? thanks!

Comment: thanks. i put the `break` in, then I get this error messagge `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with message 'RecursiveDirectoryIterator::__construct(core/controller/,core/controller/): The system cannot find the path specified. (code: 3)' in C:\wamp\www\xxx\initiator.php on line <i>126</i>` line 126 refers to `$recursive_directory = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path_directory);` how come?

Comment: Not sure but ``/`` and ``\`` in the paths might be significant in different platforms. You can try ``DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR``. Eg) ``'core/controller/'`` to ``'core' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'controller' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR``. And... how about adding ``.`` or ``__DIR__`` at the beginning of the paths to make it explicitly relative of absolute?

Comment: `str_replace('\\', '/', $file->getPath())` I tried with this but no luck at all.

Comment: Before feeding ``$path_directory`` to ``new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path_directory);`` you can test ``if(!is_dir($path_directory)){ echo 'non-existing:'.$path_directory; exit(1); }`` to see what's going on.

Comment: The problem comes from `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` - it loops the directories and lists all files. But what I want is only the sub directories.

Answer (score -1):

Open the start menu. In the text box write `cmd`, wait for the `cmd` program to pop up and then hit Enter.

Once the terminal window opens navigate to your root folder and then do a recursive search (through all files and folders) for the class' name:

```
cd C:\wamp\www\xxx
findstr /SNIP /C:"class common" *.php
```

There should be more than one declaration of the class.

Comment: The problem comes from `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` - it loops the directories and lists all files. But what I want is only the sub directories.